# Is meteor's package aldeed:autoform insecure?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

In my way learning Meteor the past weeks, trying to build a simple crud with some validation I stumbled upon something.

Until today, I've been trying to keep my Collection Schema on server's side, and had some difficulties rendering Schemas server validation on the client, so I added aldeed:autoform.

When I started playing with autoform, after a few errors, I was surprised to realize that a Collection's Schema HAD to be defined on client side in order to work properly.

Doesn't that seems a bit dangerous? Should the schema of your Collections be published on the client?

It is maybe a stupid question, im not sure. I'll apologize in advance :D

Comment: I don't think so. If you didn't use autoform, you would have some code providing form validation, which would tell a hacker which items are required. I don't think that means its a security hole

Comment: But that code providing validation would be "secured" in server's side, not on client side, exposing potentially sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the schema so that it is accessible by both the client and the server code. This is because, the form validation is done once at the client side (which should be always treated as insecure as it's made available in the browser console like below) and once on the server side. The server side validation is always considered secure. So even if you manage to manipulate the form from the browser by whatever means, if the validation does not fall in line with the schema, it gets filtered out on the server side **so long as the schema is attached to the collection**. I believe this way it's secure.

[image]

[Meteor autoform page](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#example) suggests you to remove insecure and add allow/deny rules.

> Be sure to define proper insert security for untrusted code if you've
>   removed the `insecure` package. Call allow/deny or use
>   [ongoworks:security](https://atmospherejs.com/ongoworks/security).

Steps I follow to keep things secure (please be aware that there may be better ways, since I'm also fairly new to meteor universe)

1. Remove autopublish and insecure.
2. Define schema with allow/deny rules.
3. Use meteor server methods to insert / update.
4. Whether you use the schema attached to a collection or a schema to just validate a form and not really want it to be attached to a collection, make sure you call `[check()][4]` on the server code so that the once the form is submitted at the client end to the server, the server further explicitly checks if the data is still in accordance with the schema and nothing has been injected / tampered with by someone or something untrusted. **If it is manipulated, the server side validation automatically filters out the extra additions on to the data passed to it**.

This is what happens if someone adds extra data into which does not exist / conform to the schema definition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed post, but I still think that exposing your schema to the client can provide information that can be exploited. I'm going to write a new question, as this one is misleading.